# Solving vector equations

Tags: vectors

If I know that the intersection of the two lines
$r$ vector = $x(\frac a{|a|}| + \frac b{|b|})$ and
$r$ vector = $2b + y(c - b)$
Is a point with with position vector $Z(\frac a{|a|} + \frac b{|b|})$ then what is Z?

A)  the AM between |b| and |a|
B) the GM between |b| and |c|
C). The HM between |b| and |c|
D) |b| + |c|

What is the explanation?

Comment: Please post your attempts, how you tackled the problem, and where did you get stuck.